# Convert character into date format

Tags: r, date

I currently have a database with dates in character format `yyyy-mm` format. e.g. `2009-01` and missing values.

I'm struggling to convert this into a date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ym` from `lubridate` package:

```
lubridate::ym('2009-01')
#[1] "2009-01-01"
```